# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at XMLHttpRequest.ajax.onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, ajax

I don't know why this error keeps on popping up, sometimes the code will work fine, and sometimes it won't and I'll get that error which is very annoying

```
var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var method="GET";
                    var url="getMessages.php";
                    var asynchronous=true;
                    ajax.open(method, url,asynchronous);
                    ajax.send();
                    ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
                          var data=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                           console.log(data);
                           var html="";
                           for(var b=0;b<data.length;b++){
                               var ID=data[b].ID;
                               var name=data[b].name;
                               var email=data[b].email;
                               var subject=data[b].subject;
                               var message=data[b].message;
                               var link = `management.php?delete=${ID}`;
                                 html +="<tr>";
                                 html +=`<td><a href='${link}'>Delete</a></td>`;
                                 html +="<td>" + name + "</td>";
                                 html +="<td>" + email + "</td>";
                                 html +="<td>" + subject + "</td>";
                                 html +="<td>" + message + "</td>";
                                html +="</tr>";
                               

                           }
                           document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += html;
                           
                        } 
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you're doing without showing your HTML, or a minimal working example. - Based on what you've provided, my guess is that since the initial value of your `var html=""` you're getting the error.

Put a check in your code to add a default value if html is null, or just give it a default value.

Example:

```
if (html === "") {
html = //something
}
```